# Swift compiler throws an error after archiving custom class data to UserDefaults

Tags: struct, nskeyedarchiver, userdefaults

I have an array of bank cards and want to save it once in order not to download data from server several times. So, the problem is that I can't archive objects of class "Card" that I declared. Card class consists of four fields as you can see and I believe the key of this issue lies in a CardInfo struct, because as far as I'm concerned, structs can't conform the NSCoding protocol. I found a solution that wrapped a struct into a class, but these manipulations didn't help.

```
struct CardInfo
{
    let type: CardType
    let title: CardProducer
    let number: String
    let cvv: Int
}

extension CardInfo{
    class Coding: NSObject, NSCoding{
        let cardInfo: CardInfo!

        init(cardInfo: CardInfo!){
            self.cardInfo = cardInfo
            super.init()
        }

        required init?(coder aDecoder:NSCoder) {
            guard let type = CardType(rawValue: aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "type") as! Int), let title = CardProducer(rawValue:aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "title") as! Int), let number = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "number") as? String, let cvv = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "cvv") as? Int else { return nil }
            cardInfo = CardInfo(type: type, title: title, number: number, cvv: cvv)
            super.init()
        }

        func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {

            guard let cardInfo = cardInfo else { return }

            aCoder.encode(cardInfo.type.rawValue, forKey: "type")
            aCoder.encode(cardInfo.title.rawValue, forKey: "title")
            aCoder.encode(cardInfo.number, forKey: "number")
            aCoder.encode(cardInfo.cvv, forKey: "cvv")
        }


    }
}


class Card: NSObject, NSCoding{
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let info: CardInfo
    let balance: Int

    init(id: Int, title: String, info: CardInfo, balance: Int) {
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
        self.info = info
        self.balance = balance
    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(self.id, forKey: "id")
        aCoder.encode(self.title, forKey: "title")
        aCoder.encode(self.balance, forKey: "balance")
        aCoder.encode(self.info, forKey: "info")
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.id = aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "id")
        self.title = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "title") as! String
        self.info = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "info") as! CardInfo
        self.balance = aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "balance")
    }

}
```

Compiler throws an error after these lines.

```
UserDefaults.standard.saveObject(object:self.cards, key: "cards")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

Where saveObject is my custom method that saves defaults, and it works fine with objects of other classes.

Comment: Don't fight the framework. Adding a nested class as an extension of a struct   does not adopt the NSCoding protocol. If conforming to NSCoding is crucial turn your structs into classes inheriting from `NSObject` and adopt NSCoding the usual way.

Comment: @vadian Actually I've solved it replacing the struct by class, thx.